# Toolbar is stuck most of the times when using it in coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, coordinator-layout

I am inflating fragments in the FrameLayout and the fragments have the root layout as NestedScrollView. While scrolling up and down, my toolbar gets stuck and does not come back or sometimes it does not scroll. Any solutions???

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_height="1dp"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_lin_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_left_dwrawer_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"></FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: how did you fix this

Comment: by adding 1 dp line below the toolbar.